# Can't get login page to redirect when user credentials are entered

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm having so problem with a little project I've been working on. I'm trying to learn as much as I can about html, php, MySQL, etc. I created a database with MySQL and I know that I have that setup correctly, because the login page I'm using is able to know what is the right, and wrong user accounts. I cant seem to be able to get the page to redirect to the welcome page on a successful login. Here is my code.

Login Page Code

```
<?php
include("config.php");
session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  // username and password sent from form 

  $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
  $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

  $sql = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username = '$myusername' and passcode = '$mypassword'";
  $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $active = $row['active'];

  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

  if($count == 1) {
     session_register("myusername");
     $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;

     header("location: welcome.php");
  }else {
     $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
  }
}
?>
  <html>

  <head>
  <title>Login Page</title>

  <style type = "text/css">
     body {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
     }

     label {
        font-weight:bold;
        width:100px;
        font-size:14px;
     }

     .box {
        border:#666666 solid 1px;
     }
     </style>

     </head>

     <body bgcolor = "#FFFFFF">

     <div align = "center">
     <div style = "width:300px; border: solid 1px #333333; " align = "left">
        <div style = "background-color:#333333; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>

        <div style = "margin:30px">

           <form action = "" method = "post">
              <label>UserName  :</label><input type = "text" name =     "username" class = "box"/><br /><br />
              <label>Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = "password" class = "box" /><br/><br />
              <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br />
           </form>

           <div style = "font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php echo $error; ?></div>

        </div>

     </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Session Code

```
<?php
include('config.php');
session_start();

$user_check = $_SESSION['myusername'];

$ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"select username from admin where username = '$user_check' ");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$login_session = $row['username'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  header("location:welcome.php");
}
?>
```

Redirected Page

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<html>

 <head>
  <title>Welcome </title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <h1>Welcome <?php echo $login_session; ?></h1> 
  <h2><a href = "logout.php">Sign Out</a></h2>
 </body>

</html>
<?php
session_start();

if(session_destroy()) {
  header("Location: login.php");
}
strong text ?>
```

Comment: You are mixing  **$_SESSION['myusername']; $row['username']** and **$_SESSION['username']**

Comment: And your session.php is wrong. In case of error it redirects to welcome.php so you will get stuck in a redirect loop

Comment: And if the login page throws no error, echo $error will cause errors, wich is quite funny :) . Do $error="" somewhere

Comment: stop using session_register. you can directly add session variables

Comment: Ok, So what I'm getting from your answers is that I need to change this like this?  **$_SESSION['myusername']; $row['username'] and $_SESSION['myusername']** and then I need to change my session.php to redirect back to the login.php

Comment: Before you do anything else, look up "SQL injection attack".  Your login page will survive about 15 secs in the wild before your site is taken over.

Comment: @Gh0st_Rider, check my solution

Comment: @ChrisCaviness, absolutely right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 include("config.php");


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// username and password sent from form

$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username = '$myusername' and passcode = '$mypassword'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$active = $row['active'];

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count == 1) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
    header("Location: welcome.php");
}else {
    $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
    header("Location: login.php?error=".$error);
}
}
else {

if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    echo $_GET['error'];
}

?>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        label {
            font-weight: bold;
            width: 100px;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .box {
            border: #666666 solid 1px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<div align="center">
    <div style="width:300px; border: solid 1px #333333; " align="left">
        <div style="background-color:#333333; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>

        <div style="margin:30px">

            <form action="" method="post">
                <label>UserName :</label><input type="text" name="username" class="box"/><br/><br/>
                <label>Password :</label><input type="password" name="password" class="box"/><br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value=" Submit "/><br/>
            </form>

            <div style="font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php echo $error; ?></div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

this is Session Code

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 include('config.php');


 $user_check = $_SESSION['myusername'];

 $ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"select username from admin where username = '$user_check' ");

 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

 $login_session = $row['username'];

 ?>
```

Redirected Page

```
 <?php
 include('session.php');
 ?>
<html>
 <head>
<title>Welcome </title>
</head>

 <body>
 <h1>Welcome <?php echo $login_session; ?></h1>
 <h2><a href = "logout.php">Sign Out</a></h2>
 </body>

 </html>
 <?php
 session_start();

 if(session_destroy()) {
 header("Location: login.php");
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: I tried your solution Coder, but when I try to enter my login credentials it doesn't redirect me anywhere. It still gives me the error if I type in the username and password wrong, but I'm not being redirected at all.

Comment: just change header("location:welcome.php") to header("Location:welcome.php") same with login.php. I have updated my ans

Answer (score 0):

Oh... you can't set headers after some html elements. If you want to redirect with php, you have to basically set it before anything loads. You can still simply redirect using some javascript tho...

```
<script>window.location="index.html";</script>
```

that makes you go back to index just when you let it run.

I hope I helped. I'm 19, and at same tracks as you bud! have fun!

Comment: Just to help a little bit more...
when you set headers, it is handled server side by apache (your php script running). Since it's server side, you don't even know if youre redirected or not, since your client is just waiting that request...

But by using javascript, your opening a window so the person can visualize that page just before the script runs... so beware what you print on this one page.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try it, I think this is useful for you,

header('Location: http://www.example.com/welcome.php');
```

and try to change location of session_start(); top of the config.

Comment: He create session for user name, and he want welcome.php page after login, header() function give it's. so I recommended him it, he is not add whole path in header function. if he add complete function then may be it's do work.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of reasons. The most probable one is that the script doesn't exit after issuing the header. Note, that `header()` merely adds a header to the page, but doesn't stop further execution. So the login page recognizes your login, issues the redirect header, but the execution continues and the login form is rendered again, which stops redirect.

Suggested: put `exit;` after the `header()` call.

Another possible reason there's something output before the header goes out. I.e. if you accidentally produce any text and then call `header(...)` - the the header won't do anything. This issue can be detected by PHP, you should receive a warning in such a case. Make sure, that you have enabled errors and warnings - check that `error_reporting` is set to `E_ALL` and  `display_errors` is turned `on` in your ini file. This will help you see a lot of issues, while developing.

You would also benefit from a couple of debugging tools to understand what goes wrong in this case. In the order by easiness to use immediately:

1. Browser dev tools. Right click on the page in your browser, select Inspect. It will open you the browser development tools. In particular you're interested in Network requests tab. Switch to it and then re-submit the login form. You will see the request in the tab. Examine it: was the header present there? Was the method POST as you intended? What was the response body?
2. Debugging proxy. E.g. [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for Windows, [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) for OSX.
   This is a software, that helps you see all the requests made by your browser. If your workflow has multiple redirects, then browser's Network tab won't show you anything except the last request. While proxy will store all the urls and let you examine how the case evolved.
3. PHP Debugger - install and activate [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/), setup your IDE (do you use one?) to use that. It will help you step through the PHP code and see whether the algorithm indeed worked right.